# While loading webpage: "undefined method `request_uri' for #"

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to use Ruby to load a webpage over HTTP and check what its status code is. My code looks like this:

```
  require "net/http"
  @r = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(myURL))
  return @r.code
```

However, for some URLs (mostly ones pointing to weird stuff like web counters that won't give a proper response) I'm getting an `undefined method request_uri for #` exception. I've traced it back to line 380 of http.rb (I'm running Ruby 1.8), where it says:

```
def HTTP.get_response(uri_or_host, path = nil, port = nil, &block)
  if path
    host = uri_or_host
    new(host, port || HTTP.default_port).start {|http|
      return http.request_get(path, &block)
    }
  else
    uri = uri_or_host
    new(uri.host, uri.port).start {|http|
      return http.request_get(uri.request_uri, &block) <--- LINE 380
    }
  end
end
```

I'm quite lost as to what causes this exception. I would expect a `URI::InvalidURIError`, but not this.

Comment: This is not an answer so I post it as a comment. I hit this error when converting a Rails 3.0 app to a Rails 3.1 app, here: session[:return_to] = request.request_uri

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Given a recognised scheme (e.g. http/https), a more specialised class will be instantiated.  Otherwise a "generic" URI is created; the idea of a "request URI" only makes sense for some URI schemes.

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> URI.parse('http://www.google.com/').class
=> URI::HTTP
irb(main):003:0> URI.parse('https://www.google.com/').class
=> URI::HTTPS
irb(main):004:0> URI.parse('foo://www.google.com/').class
=> URI::Generic
irb(main):005:0> URI.parse('http://www.google.com/').respond_to?(:request_uri)
=> true
irb(main):006:0> URI.parse('https://www.google.com/').respond_to?(:request_uri)
=> true
irb(main):007:0> URI.parse('foo://www.google.com/').respond_to?(:request_uri)
=> false
```

So one of the URIs you're parsing has a strange scheme -- even though it's a valid URI -- that's all.

Comment: Oh, haha, when checking if a request_uri method exists I was on the wrong docs page.

Comment: One-liner that should work for most types of URIs: `uri.try(:request_uri) || uri.to_s` (try will return `nil` if the object doesn't respond to the message)

Comment: Old topic, but I found `try` not to be working. Alternatively you can use `defined? uri.request_uri ? uri.request_uri : uri.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

First off, as to why it's `#`, my guess is that this error is appearing in the browser and is therefore being considered HTML. Try viewing source and seeing if it's not `#<ObjectWhatever>`.

As for the error, that sounds correct. It just means that the URI object you're using has no `request_uri` method. Maybe you meant to use `path`?