# oauth rails error - undefined method `request_uri' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I was using Oauth in my project for quite a long time (and I am sure it was working before), but after some time it has broken for all providers at the same time and for all providers (facebook, vkontakte, twitter)

The error is

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token>
```

I tried to downgrade to ruby 1.9.0 (from 2.1.0) - it is still the same

Full stack is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000101ee8f48>):
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `create_request'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:82:in `perform_request'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
faraday (0.9.1) lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/client.rb:93:in `request'
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/client.rb:138:in `get_token'
oauth2 (1.0.0) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:93:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:115:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:77:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:73:in `block in callback_phase'
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:136:in `with_authorization_code!'
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:72:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
```

Does anybody has the same?

Comment: Please check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-absolute-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [While loading webpage: "undefined method \`request\_uri' for #"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291919/while-loading-webpage-undefined-method-request-uri-for)

Comment: Please notice that this is not my code in the backtrace. And the URL (https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token) seems to be ok. Should I update oauth to specific version?

Comment: Actually it is not clear why I have URI::Generic and not URI::Https

Comment: Try to update `omniauth-*` gems. `URI::Generic` do not implement `request_uri`, but `URI::Http` yes and `URI::Https` by inherit, seems like your code have hardcoded the URL.

Comment: my omniauth-facebook (2.0.1) seems to be the new one